# Certificate marked as "not trusted by CA

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ssl-certificate-errors

I have a rather surprising problem these last days on one of my certificates signed by my root CA (via AD-CS).

I noticed that my browser sends me back a message that I have never seen in place of my CA.
However, my CA is well installed on the server hosting my web application, this CA is well deployed on the users' workstations and the certificate in question (*.plan-loire.fr in this case) was well signed and delivered by my CA (AELB-CA).
Note that it is an application only accessible internally, hence the use of a private CA.
Other applications on the same server and using the same CA do not have this problem.
I also regenerated my certificate from scratch and re-signed it by my CA.

I attach the message returned by my browser.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

[Certificate marked as "not trusted by CA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDZIR.png)

Comment: Does the hostname of the server match the wild card format you have in the cert? Or is it reverting to IP in the address bar?

Comment: The hostname of the server corresponds to my certificate, and I only access it via the hostname in the address bar